# How to set my log file name dynamically from a script?

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging

I created a logging.conf file that works pretty well for one process. It logs everything correctly on the right file:

```
[loggers]
keys=root

[logger_root]
handlers=screen,file
level=DEBUG

[formatters]
keys=simple,complex

[formatter_simple]
format=%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s

[formatter_complex]
format=%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(module)s : %(lineno)d - %(message)s

[handlers]
keys=file,screen

[handler_file]
class=handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler
interval=midnight
backupCount=7
formatter=complex
level=DEBUG
args=('../logs/my_log.log',)

[handler_screen]
class=StreamHandler
formatter=simple
level=DEBUG
args=(sys.stdout,)
```

And thats how I get my logger object inside my script:

```
# Create logger
logging.config.fileConfig('../logging.conf')
logger = logging.getLogger()
```

The problem is - Now I have more than one process using the same script, and ***both are using the same log file***, what is causing a concurrency error. 
How can I set my log file name from inside of my script? There is a way to set the `args=('../logs/my_log.log',)` attribute of the `[handler_file]` dynamically?

Answer (score 1):

You can create the file handler at runtime in the script

```
filehandler = logging.FileHandler("process1.log")
filehandler.setFormatter( ... )
logger.addHandler(filehandler)
```

See https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#logging-advanced-tutorial for detailed documentation

Comment: I understand. The problem is that I would like to change a handler parameter at runtime, not create the entire handler at runtime...